# Display first 3 items

Tags: c++

I have a linked list that contains 5 data items as shown in the code below and 
I would like to display only the first 3 items.

```
void insertlist(string na, double co)
{
link *pnewlink=new link(na, co);
pnewlink->pnext=pfirst;
pfirst=pnewlink;
    }

 void displaylist() {
linked * pcurrent;
pcurrent = pfirst;

while (pcurrent != NULL) {
  pcurrent-> display();
  pcurrent = pcurrent-> pnext;
}
}

};

 int main() {
 linkedlist x;

 x.insertlist("Bread", 50.00);
 x.insertlist("Salt", 650.00);
 x.insertlist("Milk", 70.00);
 x.insertlist("Sugar", 45.00);
 x.insertlist("Honey", 450.00);
 x.displaylist();

 return 0;
 }
```

**I would really appreciate your help**

Comment: This is incomplete.  Any reason you are not using std::list?

Comment: Yes I just posted this half because the website won't allow me be post a long code.I  am not using the other method because I amnot familiar with it

Comment: Generally when we see examples like this with someone's own list implementation, it's because they're completing homework where the point is to learn some data structure. Is that the case here?

Comment: Is there a difference between `insertlist` and `insert`?

Comment: that is exactly the case .I am trying to do a homework and there is no difference between  insert and insertlist. Seems like I forgot to add list

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the correct code.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that just by adding a few lines to your displaylist function. You just need a counter for that. For example:

```
void displaylist3() {
   linked * pcurrent;
   pcurrent = pfirst;

   int counter = 0;
   while (pcurrent && counter < 3) {
    pcurrent-> display();
    pcurrent = pcurrent-> pnext;
    counter++;
   }
 }
```